# How to assign specific users to specific controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP NET MVC 5 Internet Application, I have two types of users. I would like to know how to prevent a user from performing action methods in the other user's controllers.

Comment: have you read about user roles?

Answer (score 4):

Action is only available to  only the specified users

```
// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Jhon,Bob")]
public ActionResult Index()
{   
}
```

Or if you want role wise then use it

```
// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Or controller is only available to users in the Administrators roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{

}
```

Or limit access to a controller to only the specified users

```
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class RestrictedContentController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but be wary of hard coding user names in the code.  Every new user will require a new build which sucks pretty bad sometimes.  Just use the Roles functionality and then you can assign the users in the database or administrative application.

Comment: @KennethGarza Thanks for your comment.Yes, i know that :)